# How to open particular folder using intent in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-application, cordova-plugin-camera

I am trying to open specific folder using intent since I need to pass the picked data from that folder to my cordova app. Is there any solution for this issue?

Following is the code which I am using currently :-

```
Intent intent =  new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/folder_name/");
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "resource/folder");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

 if (this.cordova != null) 
{
            this.cordova.startActivityForResult((CordovaPlugin) this, Intent.createChooser(intent,
                    new String(title)), (srcType + 1) * 16 + returnType + 1);
 }
```

By this code user first has to select a file explorer upon which the file explorer shows the content of that folder.
But my requirement is to directly open the contents of that particular specified folder and to be able to pick the video.
Can anybody help me in this?

Comment: `This gives me all the content of my folder`. ??? Dont believe that. Who would show that content? And how? What does the user see?

Comment: To greenapps,  I have made this changes in cordova-camera -plugin java code and it is showing me contents of my "GIF" folder using file manager. Tested it with ES file explorer. So this is working code. But since there is ACTION_VIEW it gives various video player options after clicking on video.

Comment: So you posted code with which the user first has to select a file explorer upon which the file explorer shows the content of that folder?

Comment: To greenapps, Yes, but my requirement is to directly open the contents of that particular specified folder and to be able to pick the video. Could you help me with that?

Comment: So `This gives me all the content of my folder` was not true. As it gave a dialog from which the user could pick a file explorer or yet other apps. I'm not very happy with the way you described what the posted code does.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Well why dont you post code for Intent.CALL_MY_MOTHER too? What does ACTION_VIEW have to do with ACTION_PICK? Letting the the user VIEW somthing with the help of an app is something different from letting the user PICK/SELECT an item. Further it is strange you have videos in a gif folder. You should post your ACTION_PICK code or those you tried.

Comment: I m actually trying this in cordova plugin.I want the user to be able to pick selected item and show it in my app. As soon as I set  intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK), even the folder doesn't appear. I get a message "No apps can perform this action" . With Action_view, atleast i get to see the folder in my app.

Comment: `How to open particular folder using intent in android?` You changed the subject. Now you made a complete mess out of it. You already know how to do that you told. But you want to let the user pick a file or more files. A mess it is.

Comment: ACTION_PICK will not do what you want. You are better off using a file picker. You can find abundant code on the internet to include in your app. You can also install file picker/explorer apps who do what you need. Like OI File Manager. You have a lot of possibilities.

Comment: Further. Using ACTION_GET_CONTENT instead off ACTION_PICK and specifying the source dir as you did the user can select ES FIle Explorer which shows all the files in that dir. If the user clicks a file you get it in onActivityResult().